# Solving for the values of (x+y) upto 3 decimal places.

Tags: number-theory, logarithms, contest-math

> Given a equation:
>   $72^x48^y=6^{xy}$ where $x,y\in \Bbb Q \ne 0$
>   Find the value of $(x+y)$

I tried using $\log$ but always end up with 2 variables $x,y$.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply logarithms, so 
$$ x\ln 72+y\ln 48=xy\ln 6$$
or by expanding the integers $72=2^33^2$, $49=2^43^1$, $6=2^13^1$
$$ 3x\ln 2+2x\ln3+4y\ln 2+y\ln 3=xy\ln 2+xy\ln3$$
As $\ln2$ and $\ln3$ are rationally independent and $x,y$ are rational, this gives us in fact two equations
$$\begin{align}3x+4y&=xy\\2x+\hphantom{0}y&=xy\end{align} $$
By equating the expressions for $xy$, $3x+4y=2x+y$, i.e., 
$$ x=-3y.$$
Substituting this gives us
$-5y=-3y^2$, hence either $y=0$ (and then $x=0$, but that solution was excluded) or $$y=\frac 53\qquad\text{and}\qquad x=-5.$$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen- Thanks for giving your time and solution.

Comment: The question seems to suggest that it is be possible to find $x+y$ without finding $x$ and $y$. I only got as far as $x+y=\frac{2}{5}xy$.

Comment: @ihf- I also got stuck there but later on solved it.